# How I will show the touch point in another view with zoom (OpenCV cropping)

Tags: ios, opencv, crop

I can crop an image easily by openCV. But I want a zooming view will be created when crop rect point is touched. But get nothing related this. Moreover, this is my 1st openCV project. I want Like this image:

[image]

My crop operation is given below:

```
-(void)singlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
CGPoint posInStretch = [gesture locationInView:_cropRect];
if(gesture.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
    [_cropRect findPointAtLocation:posInStretch];
}
if(gesture.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
    _cropRect.activePoint.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    _cropRect.activePoint = nil;
    [_cropRect checkangle:0];
}
[_cropRect moveActivePointToLocation:posInStretch];

}
```

Crop action is here:

```
- (IBAction)doneAction:(id)sender {

_titleOutlet.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Rotation", @"Message");

if([_cropRect frameEdited]){

    //Thanks To stackOverflow
    CGFloat scaleFactor =  [_sourceImageView contentScale];
    CGPoint ptBottomLeft = [_cropRect coordinatesForPoint:1 withScaleFactor:scaleFactor];
    CGPoint ptBottomRight = [_cropRect coordinatesForPoint:2 withScaleFactor:scaleFactor];
    CGPoint ptTopRight = [_cropRect coordinatesForPoint:3 withScaleFactor:scaleFactor];
    CGPoint ptTopLeft = [_cropRect coordinatesForPoint:4 withScaleFactor:scaleFactor];

    NSLog(@"ptBottomLeft=%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(ptBottomLeft));
    NSLog(@"ptBottomRight=%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(ptBottomRight));
    NSLog(@"ptTopRight=%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(ptTopRight));
    NSLog(@"ptTopLeft=%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(ptTopLeft));

    CGFloat w1 = sqrt( pow(ptBottomRight.x - ptBottomLeft.x , 2) + pow(ptBottomRight.x - ptBottomLeft.x, 2));
    CGFloat w2 = sqrt( pow(ptTopRight.x - ptTopLeft.x , 2) + pow(ptTopRight.x - ptTopLeft.x, 2));

    CGFloat h1 = sqrt( pow(ptTopRight.y - ptBottomRight.y , 2) + pow(ptTopRight.y - ptBottomRight.y, 2));
    CGFloat h2 = sqrt( pow(ptTopLeft.y - ptBottomLeft.y , 2) + pow(ptTopLeft.y - ptBottomLeft.y, 2));

    CGFloat maxWidth = (w1 < w2) ? w1 : w2;
    CGFloat maxHeight = (h1 < h2) ? h1 : h2;



    cv::Point2f src[4], dst[4];
    src[0].x = ptTopLeft.x;
    src[0].y = ptTopLeft.y;
    src[1].x = ptTopRight.x;
    src[1].y = ptTopRight.y;
    src[2].x = ptBottomRight.x;
    src[2].y = ptBottomRight.y;
    src[3].x = ptBottomLeft.x;
    src[3].y = ptBottomLeft.y;

    dst[0].x = 0;
    dst[0].y = 0;
    dst[1].x = maxWidth - 1;
    dst[1].y = 0;
    dst[2].x = maxWidth - 1;
    dst[2].y = maxHeight - 1;
    dst[3].x = 0;
    dst[3].y = maxHeight - 1;

    cv::Mat undistorted = cv::Mat( cvSize(maxWidth,maxHeight), CV_8UC4);
    cv::Mat original = [MMOpenCVHelper cvMatFromUIImage:_adjustedImage];


    NSLog(@"%f %f %f %f",ptBottomLeft.x,ptBottomRight.x,ptTopRight.x,ptTopLeft.x);
    cv::warpPerspective(original, undistorted, cv::getPerspectiveTransform(src, dst), cvSize(maxWidth, maxHeight));

    [UIView transitionWithView:_sourceImageView duration:0.1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{



        _sourceImageView.image=[MMOpenCVHelper UIImageFromCVMat:undistorted];
        _cropImage=_sourceImageView.image;

        //         _sourceImageView.image = [MMOpenCVHelper UIImageFromCVMat:grayImage];//For gray image

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        _cropRect.hidden=YES;
        //        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        //        scrollView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 64);

        //        }];

    }];

    original.release();
    undistorted.release();
}
else{
    UIAlertView  *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Alert", nil) message:NSLocalizedString(@"Invalid Rect", nil) delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil) otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find origin of your "lens" ROI, crop it to separate image, scale it say factor=2 each dimension, then crop from scaled ROI central part with offset dx=(ROI_width-ROI_width*factor)*0.5  and dy=(ROI_height-ROI_height*factor)*0.5, size=(ROI_width,ROI_height), and put new cropped image back to your initial ROI on source image. You can also apply round mask as on your image, on copying.

Comment: Now, I can show easily the touch point in another imageView but how I will show the cropped image portion and crop rect simultaneously in another view. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Just use separate copy of image to crop the ROI, and another image copy to show pasted view. You can use src.copyTo(dst(ROI)) method to put cropped view to your image.